# Why does my wireless card appears in iwconfig as a eth interface?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I wanted to identify my wireless network interface name to check my wireless network card is installed properly or not . But i am getting something different.

I'm used to seeing this:

```
$ /sbin/iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Tx-Power=20 dBm
```

but I am now seeing this:

```
$ /sbin/iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"REPALLE"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: C0:A0:BB:17:12:6E   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Why is my wireless card showing up as an eth interface instead of a wifi or wlan interface, and how can I make it appear as I expect?

Comment: That's just a name... Does your wifi card work?

Answer (score 0):

The Broadcom wireless driver provided by bcmwl-kernel-source, as well as some older Intel drivers, names the wireless interface ethxy, where *xy* is the next available eth interface name. The driver does provide a parameter you may change. I have no Broadcom card so I've never tried this, so the process may or may not work as expected. In a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options wl intf_name=wlan0"  > /etc/modprobe.d/bcmwl.conf
rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
exit
```

Reboot and your interface is probably wlan0.

Comment: Thanks chili555 my interface name is changed to wlan0 but still i am not getting the desired output :-    wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Tx-Power=20 dBm

Comment: Is Network Manager set to Infrastructure mode? Or what? Does it help to do: sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed

Comment: how can i set Network Manager set to Infrastructure mode? @chili555

Comment: Right-click the NM icon, select Edit Connections > Wireless > Edit > and change Mode to Infrastructure. Save and close.

Comment: ya its in infrastucture mode.

Comment: Does it help to do: sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed

Comment: ya its giving mode as managed but in the above output the mode is Monitor.

Comment: So does it always come up as monitor on boot? If NM is set to Infrastructure, it ought to start that way by default. Doesn't it?

Comment: on booting some information are showing about this wireless and bluetooth .

Comment: Can you post it or find it in dmesg? In /var/log/syslog? If it is lengthy, post here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give us the link.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8083023/

Comment: I don't see anything remarkable there. wlan0 starts as expected and connects perfectly. If you can capture anything from boot, I'll be happy to check it. Your logs look just fine!

Comment: ok. thanks Actually the thing is that i wanted to use aircrack-ng but i am not able to do it . could you do some help.